# SharePoint 2016 Services stopped in web Front-end suddenly

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I have critical issue with our SharePoint Server 2016.

The architecture consists of a web-tier, an application server tier, and a database tier, and roles are Application with Search & Front-end with Distributed Cache

The issue is: The following services

- SharePoint Search Host Controller,
- SharePoint Timer Service,
- SharePoint Tracing Service

are suddenly stopped in Web Front-end.

On the other hand, I tried to run "SharePoint Configuration Wizard" in application server tier, unfortunately got Error screen with message

> Server Farm product and patch status" ; There is set of patches(KB4018293 & KB3203433 & KB3128017) are missing in both servers (Application Server, and Web Front-end Server),

even though these patches have already been installed before. I

I executed this command `Get-SPProduct -local` based on Microsoft recommendation to resolve this issue, but no any changes.

In the same time, I tried to run "SharePoint Configuration Wizard" in Web Front-end server tier, unfortunately got Error screen with message

> Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.
>   This is a critical task. You have to fix the failures before you can continue.
>
> ---
>
> An exception of type System.ArgumentException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Absolute path information is required.

Answer (score 2):

we had this type of issue in past with SP 2013, in our case, System drive (C:) running out of space and windows admin delete some files from that drive to free up space but he deleted bunch of msi which related to sharepoint installation and at the end that server having the issues like you are getting.

What we did, we installed the last cu, which we applied to the farm, on the server and run the config wizard and that fix the issue.

I would stat with [ROISCAN](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/68b80aba-130d-4ad4-aa45-832b1ee49602)  and get the list which is missing.

> Robust Office Inventory Scan (ROIScan.vbs) is a Microsoft Visual Basic
> script that collects Office data and provides error detection and
> analysis options. When you run the script, a log file is created. The
> log file can be used to perform tasks such as the following:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221405.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396